# Should I accept an invitation to review a research paper as an undergraduate?

Tags: publications, peer-review, conference, undergraduate, invitations

I recently received an invitation to review a paper at a conference in China. This is the first time I am being invited to review. I do feel qualified to do it since I have worked on the topic for more than 3 years and also have a publication at a renowned conference and another publication in a Q1 journal. However, in the invitation e-mail, I am greeted as `Dr.`- which states to me they might be thinking that I hold a Ph.D., whereas I am still an undergraduate, in my final year. What should I do? My advisor has suggested me to accept it as he feels it would be good for me and my experience would increase since I am more into researching stuff.

Comment: Make sure that the conference is reputable, and inform them of your educational status. They haven't done their homework, I fear, which is worrisome.

Comment: I was worried about this too. But after looking into them thoroughly, I saw that the papers they accept get indexed by good places like EI Compendex, Scopus, and ACM Digital Library. And they are doing the conference for the 12th time. So my initial fear of it being fake has been mitigated from my mind. But then again, I don't know how much renowned it is. If you are interested, I can share the name/link. And thank you for your opinion and time, Professor. @Buffy

Comment: No need. You've done your homework. They likely found you due to your publication(s).

Comment: Even reputable journals and conferences often write to you as Dr. Lastname, because it's easier to assume everyone has a PhD instead of doing the research every time, so don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that they think you have a doctorate is a bit of a worry. You should probably inform them otherwise, but say you are happy to do it and feel competent to do so. Ask your advisor for advice on that.

It would be good experience for you, but the committee probably needs the heads up.

If you haven't yet seen the paper, then you may need to make the decision about your own competence after you do. There is nothing wrong with turning it down if it seems like a stretch.

Your advisor probably gives the best advice overall here.